Uniform distribution of load along with consistent hashing in ingress-nginx
How can we achieve uniform distribution of load while using upstream-hash-by (which uses consistent hashing to distribute load and to maintain stickiness).
I mean to say combine stickiness property of hash-by and even-distribution-of-load property from round robin or least connection (least_conn). Is this practically possible or any other means apart from the mentioned.
I saw that when hash-by is used, with a custom header key from clients, the load is not equally distributed among the backend pods.

You can try this approach for optimising upstream-hash-by for distribution

Selecting your hash key. You can try to combine IP address with a random value. This can help the requests to spread across backends even for clients with the same IP address.

Adding more backend servers. The distribution gets more even as you add more backend servers that can impact a single client mapping to a specific pod due to hashing is minimized.


